# IMEI code /01 explanation

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I have made many researches about the IMEI code.  But still just small thing  I couldn't find its answer.  Look.  The IMEI code is a fifteen digit.  But on some phones the IMEI code ends with "/01".
  For example : 325215005632145/01.
my question is : what's the "/01 " at the last of the IMEI code mean? What's the information that I can get it from it? . Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are probably refering to the SVN - Software Version Number. It is often displayed at the end of the IMEI (which is then named IMEISV).

While, for any given phone, IMEI is constant, SVN can change after software update.

In your case `/01` means software version 1.

Comment: According to the spec, IMEISV should be a 16 digits number. However the example has 17 digits. I assume this Samsung phone displayed a hybrid IMEI/IMEISV number?

Answer (score 2):

My personal experienced showing that Imeisv 01 mean your phone hasn't been though service (or fixing). If the number change to 2 mean it's been though service once and so on.

Comment: This should be comment

Comment: @ketan This is a valid answer and is not NAA. I noticed you left this comment on a lot of answers. Refer to [the official guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). This one is an attempt at an answer: it provides a reason for the error code. A poor, or an altogether wrong, answer does not qualify as being NAA. Feel free to come to chat and create a room if you want to discuss this further.

Comment: @Tunaki more than 90% of my comments are correct which is comment posted as answer.